# Passing array information between functions using a struct

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

I'm struggling a bit with pointers. I'm trying to pass information between functions, but am getting the following error: "request for member ‘score’ in something not a structure or union", and the same error with 'index' instead of score (and for all other members I'm doing this for that are not listed here).

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct line_t {
  char* buf;
  int lineLength;   
  int wordCount;
  int index;
  double score;
} line_t;
```

This is my call to the function in main (with declaration):

```
line_t bestmatch[TOP_SCORING_MAX];
func3(&line, &bestmatch[TOP_SCORING_MAX]);
```

Here is my function:

```
line_t
func3(line_t line, line_t *bestmatchPtr[]) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i< TOP_SCORING_MAX; i++) { 

        if (line.score != 0) {

            if (i == 0) {

                bestmatchPtr[0].score = line.score;
                bestmatchPtr[0].index = line.index;

               /*more code here: rest of func, closing of }, etc*/

return bestmatchPtr;
}
```

Essentially, I need to pass information about bestmatch between functions, while keeping it ordered (my function is attempting to order information and retain only a set amount of data). I was wondering how to fix this error?
Let me know if I'm missing some information.

Comment: Some compilers can't pass  structures or return them. Try making the retutn value be line_t *, ditto for parameter line. Remember to derefence elements with the -> operator rather than .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func3` signature should be:

```
line_t *func3(line_t line, line_t *bestmatchPtr)
/* Changed: second argument and return type */
```

Also note that:

- the last element of your array is `bestmatch[TOP_SCORING_MAX - 1]` (NOT `bestmatch[TOP_SCORING_MAX]`)
- the `line` argument is passed by value (`&line` is a pointer)

So this is wrong:

```
func3(&line, &bestmatch[TOP_SCORING_MAX]);
```

the function call should be:

```
func3(line, bestmatch);
```

Comment: Also passing `&line` will be of type `line_t*` instead `line_t`, or not?

Comment: i.e. the function call should be `func3(line, bestmatch);`